# How is compiled PL/pgSQL block?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

```
   do $$
  declare 
   tm1 timestamp without time zone;
   tm2 timestamp without time zone;
  begin
     select localtimestamp(0) into tm1;
     for i in 1..200000000 loop
        --just waiting several second
     end loop;
     select localtimestamp(0) into tm2;

      raise notice '% ; %', tm1, tm2;
  end;
  $$ language plpgsql
```

Why gives this procedure same values for `tm1` and `tm2` ?

Is not executed this code step by step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

> These SQL-standard functions all return values based on the start time of the current transaction [...] Since these functions return the start time of the current transaction, their values **do not change during the transaction**. This is considered a feature: the intent is to allow a single transaction to have a consistent notion of the "current" time, so that multiple modifications within the same transaction bear the same time stamp

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

You probably want `clock_timestamp()`